# Custom model binding with IModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write Custom model binder but it is giving an error can any one told me where i am doing it wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Ownership own = new Ownership();
        own.name = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fName"];
        own.email = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fEmail"];
        own.PhoneNo = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fPhoneNo"];
        own.country = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Country"];
        own.address = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Adres"];
        own.office = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Off"];
        own.officeEmail = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["OffEmail"];
        own.officeNo = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["OffNo"];
        own.OwnershipType = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["OwnershipType"];
        own.ProductId = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductId"];

        return own;
    }
}

}
```

Error

> "'CustomModelBinder' does not implement interface member
>   'System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder.BindModel(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext,
>   System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext)'

Comment: Have you added it in `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Ownership), new CustomModelBinder());` in global.asax? You also need `public void MyAction([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))] Ownership owner)` in the controller

Comment: Can you provide the whole file with the namespaces included?

Comment: Yes, i added it in global.asax file and also did the same as you write in controller.

Thanks for comment @artm

Comment: @danyloid: how i can share file with you ?
Thanks

Comment: @Asadkamal you can just add the namespaces to your question, or you can use any file sharing service. The code seems to be proper, my suggestion is there may be an issue with the namespaces or, maybe with the VS project cache.

Comment: @Asadkamal You need to rebuild the application. If that doesn't help, clean `bin` `obj` and the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` (the location of the last one depends on what kind of web server you are using)

Comment: @Asadkamal I totally agree with prev comment. It seems that the issue is related to the VS, not to your code. Just to check - are you using ReSharper ?

Comment: @Candide: I did it but couldn't succeed!
Thanks for Comment

Comment: @danyloid: ok let me try this on another PC !
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The **IModelBinder** which you are using is from **System.Web.ModelBinding** namespace. The BindModel method of this interface returns value of type bool.

```
bool BindModel(
    ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext,
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext
)
```

If you want to use BindModel method which returns object then you need to implement interface from **System.Web.Mvc** namespace.

```
Object BindModel(
    ControllerContext controllerContext,
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext
)
```

You can check it by providing complete namespace while implementing this IModelBinder interface. Like

```
public class CustomModelBinder : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{
   public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
               ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
 {
    Ownership own = new Ownership();
    own.name = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fName"];
    own.email = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fEmail"];
    own.PhoneNo = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["fPhoneNo"];
    own.country = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Country"];
    own.address = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Adres"];
    own.office = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Off"];
    own.officeEmail = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["OffEmail"];
    own.officeNo = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["OffNo"];
    own.OwnershipType = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["OwnershipType"];
    own.ProductId = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["ProductId"];

    return own;
}
}
```

Comment: i tried but it is not working, it gives same error on compile time